# Windows SBS Standard 2011 Folder redirection will not be disabled for one user

Tags: windows-7, folder-redirection, windows-sbs

I am trying to disable folder redirection for one user (or all users on the domain).  I have disabled the setting for the user in the users tab on the SBS console and restarted the computer a couple of times and the Desktop is still being redirected to the server. I have checked the GPO editor and nothing is set there.

Answer (score 0):

Unjoin and re-join your SBS domain from the client PC.  This has worked for me in SBS 2008, but I have not tested it in 2011

If all else fails, delete the user/computer from SBS and re-create their account. (not my favorite way to do this)

Backup the user's profile just to be safe!

Comment: I unjoined and re-joined and still can't shake this pesky folder redirection.  I will delete the user and computer and see what happens...

Comment: Ugh - I feel your pain.